# ESXi 5.1 SCSI and NMP Errors Filling vmkernel.log

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-server, scsi

On a group of ESXi 5.1 systems, I am seeing the following errors every 5 minutes or so:

```
2014-04-04T11:22:45.374Z cpu1:8193)NMP: nmp_ThrottleLogForDevice:2319: Cmd 0x1a (0x4124022be3c0, 0) to dev "t10.DP______BACKPLANE000000" on path "vmhba0:C0:T32:L0" Failed: H:0x0 D:0x2 P:0x0 Valid sense data: 0x5 0x20 0x0. Act:NONE
2014-04-04T11:22:45.374Z cpu1:8193)ScsiDeviceIO: 2331: Cmd(0x4124022be3c0) 0x1a, CmdSN 0x132a50 from world 0 to dev "t10.DP______BACKPLANE000000" failed H:0x0 D:0x2 P:0x0 Valid sense data: 0x5 0x20 0x0.
```

From [posts on the VMWare support forums](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2137344) and [VMWare KB articles](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1031221), it appears this is a known issue, and users are expected to ignore it. The log entries are generated when a rescan is attempted on the device, even though it does not support rescans. If these errors are meaningless to me, I would like a way to suppress them. There is a grep command that is in the KB article I liked above; but (obviously) this doesn't actually remove the entries.

I'm having an issue finding how to suppress the alerts and/or preventing rescans against this device. Is there any way to prevent rescans on the device that is causing these log entries?

Comment: Is this a Supermicro server? And which ESXi build number are you using?

Comment: It's a Dell server running VMkernel localhost 5.1.0 #1 SMP Release build-1312873